# HBase Storage Handler: UnknownProtocolException: No coprocessor found for name AuthenticationService hbase:meta

Tags: hive, hbase

### Error

Receiving this error with HBase Storage Handler in Hive when I run a query in a Kerberized environment.
on HBase 1.5

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException: 
        No registered coprocessor service found for name AuthenticationService in region hbase:meta,,1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:8499)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:2282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:2264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:36808)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:311)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:291)
```

The important part being:

> No registered **coprocessor** service found for name `AuthenticationService`
>   in region `hbase:meta,,1`

I did some reading and learned that `AuthenticationService` is provided by **TokenProvider** coprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `hbase-site.xml` ensure these options are configured

- `hadoop.security.authentication`
- `hbase.coprocessor.master.classes`
- `hbase.coprocessor.region.classes`

Ensure values are configured as follows:

```xml
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
```

**Note**:
In older versions of HBase the setting`hbase.coprocessor.regionserver.classes` was used, make sure you are using the correct; `hbase.coprocessor.region.classes`